# Using jquery to parse items from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using PHP and Ajax to parse some JSON. The PHP is creating the array like this.

```
$myObj->pid = $_POST["parentid"];
$myObj->comp = $comp;
$myObj->colour = $statuscolour;
$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $myJSON;
```

I use the following jquery code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "msstatup.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function(msg) {
    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(msg));
    console.log(response);
    pid = response[0].pid;
    console.log('id = ' + pid);
    });
```

I can see the output from the first console.log as

```
Object {pid: "p1", comp: 20, colour: "red"}
```

However I cannot extract the individual variables, it gives the message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pid'
```

How can I extract the variable?

Comment: Since you're returning JSON you do not have to use `parseJSON`.

Comment: Why are you first stringifying then parsing the JSON response?

Comment: You seem to be treating the response as an array when it is a single object. Try `console.log(response.pid)`

Comment: `msg.pid` is your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an object, not an array.

Also it makes no sense to stringify the data object and parse that string back to object again

Try

```
var pid = msg.pid;
console.log('id = ' + pid);
```

Answer (score 4):

You've made this more complicated than it needs to be. `msg` is already an object, which you then convert to a string and back to an object with `stringify` and `parseJSON`. And then you try to use it like an array, when it is an object.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "msstatup.php",
    data: data
}).done(function(msg) {
    var pid = msg.pid;
    console.log('id = ' + pid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it can't imagine why it would be neccessary to first stringify, then parse the JSON response.

Second, you are trying to access `response[0]` as if it were an array, which it isn't. You can simply use

```
response.pid;
```

To access the object key.

As you don't need to stringify then parse the response, you can just access `msg` directly, so it all comes down to

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "msstatup.php",
    data: data
}).done(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.pid);
});
```

Comment: `msg.pid` There is no need for the whole line of code defining `response`.

Comment: I did not DV. But, if I were that guy I would have DV'd because the original end result was not correct or at least compensating for the line of code defining `response`

Comment: You mean the typo I had in the very first save of my answer (still leaving the `[0]`), that I corrected within seconds of posting?

Comment: No, `response.pid`. While correct technically it supported the over-complication of the code.

Comment: It still was a correct answer that maybe could have used some further tweaking. Imho that's a reason to upvote other answers that cover this better, not downvote an answer. Otherwise, where do we the line of uncovered code optimisations?

Comment: I can only guess why other's might DV an answer like this. I am just trying to provide insight.